# laravel5.: GET net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: php, database, laravel, google-chrome, networking

I am creating profile page, and to upload and update image, I used **laravel-medialibrary**.

After uploading an image, I want to show an profile image again in the profile page.

In my guess, this error message is caused by google chrome.
I tried to resolve this issue. But I could not make it.
[image]

I deleted all the cache and restarted chrome, and disabled **"Predict network actions to improve page load performance or or use a prediction service to load pages more quickly"** in chrome setting menu.

Also I tried `php artisan storage:link`

These are my file structure. 
[image: File structure 1]
[image: File structure 2]
[image: File structure 3]
I want to upload an image in conversations folder which is resized.

the img src is this,

```
<img src="{{ $channel->image() }}" alt="">
```

I tried both, but I couldn't solve.

```
<img src="{{ asset($channel->image()) }}" alt="">
```

Is this problem related to database also ?
Because the image column is null.

[image: the image column is null.]

I am glad if someone helps me. 
Thank you.

This is my code.
https://github.com/YoheiUmezu/laratube

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Ok this is my code.  https://github.com/YoheiUmezu/laratube

Comment: try add `->performOnCollections('images')` inside your `registerMediaConversions`, Channel.php

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't work.                                                                                     
     $this->addMediaConversion('thumb')
            ->performOnCollections('images')
            ->width(100)
            ->height(100);

Comment: What domain is your site running on? The error you are getting means the domain could not be resolved.